# What's meaning of 혻?

Tags: korean-to-english

Actually, It used at the first of this sentence:

혻지갑 뒤져서신분증 봤어

But google translate couldn't translate it!

Do you know why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is supposed to be

> 혹시 지갑 뒤져서 신분증 봤어?
>
> The closest meaning would be 'Did you happen to see my ID card in my wallet?'

There is no 혻 in Korean, that's not a syllable.

It is definitely a mistype character while somebody is trying to type "혹시".

There is a missing 'ㅣ' between 혻 and 지.
If you put 'ㅣ' after typing 혻 then you can complete '혹시'.

---

**Further Information**

It's a tricky and risky expression though.

You can use ***"혹시 지갑 뒤져서 신분증 봤어?"*** when you have a general wonder for just **'what happened actually'**.

But you should use this expression very carefully. People often say this, putting '혹시...' in the very front when they have an underlying assumption that somebody might(or must) have done something wrong.

The listener could feel very unpleasant for that question, because he or she can probably be thinking "he must be suspecting me"

Other use case would be **a piece of advice.**

Let's say your friend lost a credit card and is busy looking for it here and there. Then you can say that to your friend there ***"혹시 지갑 뒤져봤어?"*** so that he can check his own wallet that he stupidly hasn't searched for yet.

Comment: Thank you very much :) So, can i say that its english meaning is: "I looked through your wallet" or something like "i have searched into your wallet" ?

Comment: Yes if you say it in a good way.

Comment: "뒤지다" is to rummage through something, so the meaning of the sentence is somewhat stronger than "Did you happen to see my ID...".  It's more like "Did (you) rummage through (my) wallet and look at the ID card?"  (Also note that the original sentence says neither "you" or "me" explicitly: it's inferred from the context.)

Answer (score 4):

> 혹시 지갑 뒤져서 신분증 봤어?

I believe it is misspelled.